# Kodi Addon Development: sys.argv empty list

Tags: python, kodi

I just started to look in to the development of a Kodi plugin.
However I'm stuck at finding the `process handle` of my plugin.

The [documentation](http://kodi.wiki/view/Audio/video_add-on_tutorial#Retrieving_arguments) provides this as an explanation of how you should get this 'process id'

> ... Kodi passes some arguments to us via sys.argv. This is important, since it's what will let us tailor the output on the add-on based on user input. Remember, much like a web site, each folder (or page) in an Kodi add-on is the result of a separate invocation of our script. The arguments available to us are:
>
> - **0**   The base URL of your add-on, e.g. 'plugin://plugin.video.myaddon/'
> - **1** The process handle for this add-on, as a numeric string
> - **2** The query string passed to your add-on, e.g. '?foo=bar&baz=quux'

However when I try to get this value it returns an array with only 1 element

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    baseUrl = sys.argv[0]
    processHandle = sys.argv[1]
    qs = sys.argv[2]
```

[image: debugger showing the result of the sys.argv which shows that there is nothing in the array]

I'm running `Kodi v15` on my local machine (Ubuntu 16.04) and I have a remote debugger attached. 
Any ideas to why this array does not contain the desired arguments?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are you passing as command line args?

Comment: Me? Nothing isn't this what Kodi should provide for me? Copied from the documentation:  
"... Kodi passes some arguments to us via sys.argv"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad I had an error in my `addon.xml`.
I had

```
<extension point="xbmc.python.script"
           library="addon.py">
    <provides>video</provides>
</extension>
```

instead of

```
<extension point="xbmc.python.pluginsource"
           library="addon.py">
    <provides>video</provides>
</extension>
```